# Error in query on 3 of 6 tables in linked MySQL-server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server

I am connected to a linked MySQL-server with SQL Server 2016. When I run the following query:

```
select * from openquery([servername], 'select * from database.tableName')
```

I get the error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "servername" reported an error. The provider reported an
>   unexpected catastrophic failure. Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
>   "servername".

The strange thing is that it works perfectly on three of the six tables in the database. There is no schema, and the table names are written correctly. Plees help :)

Comment: Looks like a failure in the ODBC Driver for MySQL.  You might try updating that. Or you might try using an SSIS package to load data instead.  That way you don't have to load the third-party drivers in SQL Server.  You can even "SELECT * from SSIS" using the SSIS Data Streaming Destination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-streaming-destination?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You could *try* changing your SQL to this instead:

```
exec('SELECT * FROM database.tablename') at [servername]
```

I encountered this issue when querying an AS400 from MSSQL - the above resolved my issue.

Comment: That gave the following error:
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)".